# I need to find possible values of latitude and longitude around a geometric position( with known distance )

Tags: php, math, geometry

[none  http://zoyabean.com/geo.png](http://zoyabean.com/geo.png).

How to find [ ***latx1*** , ***lonx1*** ] ,  [ ***latx2*** , ***lonx2*** ] ,  [ ***latx3*** , ***lonx3*** ] , [ ***latx4*** , ***lonx4*** ] using ***lat1*** , ***lon1***  and ***d*** from the image. ( ***lat1*** and ***lon1*** are in **degre** and ***d*** in **Km** )

> **OR**

This is the equation for finding the distance between 2 points in earth surface.

> R = 6371;    // Radious of earth.
>
> lat1 , lon1 ->   latitude and longitude of first point ( in degree )
>
> lat2 , lon2 ->   latitude and longitude of second point  ( in degree )
>
> d - >  distance b/w the two points ( in Km)

**Equation**

> dLat = (lat2-lat1)* (PI/180);
>
> dLon = (lon2-lon1)* (PI/180);
>
> a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) +  cos((lat1)* (PI/180)) * cos((lat2)* (PI/180)) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2) ;
>
> d = R * 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));

In tins equation  lat1 , lon1 , d are known

I needed to find the possible values of lat2 and lon2. [ at least  ( latx1 , lonx1 ) ,  ( latx2 , lonx2 ) ,  ( latx3 , lonx3 ) , ( latx4 , lonx4 ) ]

> ***Sorry for bad English.***

Comment: There are infinite possibilities for `lat2` and `lon2`.  Are you sure that's what you want to find?

Comment: I don't need all of them. I just need ( latx1 , lonx1 ), ( latx2 , lonx2 ), ( latx3 , lonx3 ), ( latx4 , lonx4 )

Comment: Oh, you need to know the lat/lon at 0 degrees, 90 degrees, 180 degrees, and 270 degrees?

Comment: Yes..........................

Comment: You might better ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com or maybe on http://gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570486/i-need-to-find-possible-values-of-latitude-and-longitude-around-a-geometric-posi

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK for most usages, we're only interested in **creating a test to see whether a given geo coordinate falls in the range (your circle).** (For example to be able to answer questions like "Is there a restaurant in 5 kms?" etc.) For this purpose, we already have several possibilities:

- [How do I check if a longitude/latitude point is within a range of coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510326/how-do-i-check-if-a-longitude-latitude-point-is-within-a-range-of-coordinates)
- http://our-knowledge-base.blogspot.hu/2012/04/how-to-search-within-defined-radius.html

etc.

*BTW, Brad is right. In the circle, there are infinite number of geo points in the same way as between any two integers (which aren't the same) you will find an infinite range of numbers etc.*

Comment: I'm not checking whether a geo-point with in a range. I just need that four co-ordinates ( latx1 , lonx1 ), ( latx2 , lonx2 ), ( latx3 , lonx3 ), ( latx4 , lonx4 ).